# wpf binding to client is not displaying name

Tags: c#, wpf

I've created a simple solution attempting to create a 'customer' which when the app is run, the customers name appears in the textbox of the UI. Why does it appear not to display after binding to the property and setting the datacontext?

**MainWindowViewModel.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using WpfApplication1.Model;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    class MainWindowViewModel
    {
        private Customer client = new Customer();

        public MainWindowViewModel()
        {
            client.Name = "Greg Johnson";
            client.Friends = new ObservableCollection<string>() { "Leslie", "Mitch" };
        }
    }
}
```

**XAML**

```
    <Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="300" Width="305">

    <Window.DataContext>
        <viewModel:MainWindowViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>

    <Grid>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Name}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Because `Name` is a property of `Customer`, not the `MainWindowViewModel`

Comment: So what would i modify to get it to display?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a conceptual error here. Each property binde to xaml code have to be:

1. Dependency property [here is the information](http://www.wpftutorial.net/dependencyproperties.html).
2. Implemenyt the INotifyPropertyChange interface [here is the information](http://www.wpftutorial.net/INotifyPropertyChanged.html).

only this way the binnding will work as you want it to work.
 1. Xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="NirHelpingOvalButton.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:nirHelpingOvalButton="clr-namespace:NirHelpingOvalButton"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.DataContext>
    <nirHelpingOvalButton:MainWindowViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>

<Grid>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Client.Name}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
</Grid></Window>
```

2. View model:

```
public class MainWindowViewModel:BaseObservableObject
{
    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        Client = new Customer
        {
            Name = "Steve",
            Friends = new ObservableCollection<string>(new List<string> {"John", "Alex", "Yakov"})
        };
    }

    private Customer _customer;

    public Customer Client
    {
        get { return _customer; }
        set
        {
            _customer = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

3. Model code:

```
public class Customer:BaseObservableObject
{
    private string _name;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set
        {
            _name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<string> Friends { get; set; }
}
```

4. BaseObservableObject code:

```
public class BaseObservableObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged<T>(Expression<Func<T>> raiser)
    {
        var propName = ((MemberExpression)raiser.Body).Member.Name;
        OnPropertyChanged(propName);
    }

    protected bool Set<T>(ref T field, T value, [CallerMemberName] string name = null)
    {
        if (!EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value))
        {
            field = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(name);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

5. How it is look like:
[image]

regards,

Comment: this is great. thank you for your help. this explains a good bit and helps a lot

Answer (score 5):

You need to add the property for Client in the View model. Then In the binding change to Client.Name. Refer below code.

```
class MainWindowViewModel
{
    public Customer Client { get; set; }

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        Client = new Customer();
        Client.Name = "Greg Johnson";
        Client.Friends = new ObservableCollection<string>() { "Leslie", "Mitch" };
    }
}
```

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <viewModel:MainWindowViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>

<Grid>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Client.Name}"/>
</Grid>
```